# Giving out even Numbers from 0-100 without using a Modulo-Operator with a for-loop in a c# Console

Tags: c#, for-loop, console

I just cant find a Solution to give out even Numbers without using the Modulo-Operator. I need to use a for-loop since its required by my School Assignment.
Something as Simple as Possible since im just a Beginner ._.

Comment: what about n = 2*x and x in [0..50] ? This really is not a school-assignment site, and you'll get downvoted pretty quickly for that here;

Comment: Would be so nice if even numbers would be equally spaced from each other... Like maybe 7 units - you could use `i+=7` for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, but I don't know what modulo has to do with it.
For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 2)
{
     // Only even numbers in i
}
```

Comment: Really lacks explanation... Code-only answers are not considered high quality for SO...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - True, there isn't a lot of explanation there, but I really don't know what to add. It's not a complex question, or a complex answer, but it helps the person who asked the question...

Comment: @Amit Thank you for your Answer it really helped me! I had a similar Solution like you did with i+= 2, but wrote it wrong! :)

Comment: Some people may be thrown with the `i += 2`.  Then there is my favorite linked list traversal `for(node = head; node != null && node.data != data; node = node->next);`